# Efficient way to set all empty lists in column to None in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In pandas, it is possible to do the following:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 99919 entries, 0 to 99918
Data columns (total 47 columns):
 #   Column                        Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------                        --------------  -----         
 0   reason                        99919 non-null  object
```

Most of these entries contain `[]`, and some contain an actual object, e.g. `[{'a':'x', 'b':'y', 'c':'z'}]`

I want to efficiently (**without** using `df.apply`) set all entries that contain only the empty list to e.g. `None`.

I thought that I might be able to do something like the following:

```py
df[df['reasons'].str.len() == 0]['reasons'] = None
```

but this does not work since it is setting it on a copy of the dataframe (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

Usually in the case where I set something on `df[row][column]`, I can instead do:

```py
df.loc[:, (row, column)]
```

to set it on the actual dataframe, but that does not work in this case since `df['reasons'].str.len() == 0` returns a series which is unhashable and not a valid argument for `loc`.

Is there any way to do this without using `apply`?

Comment: Use: `df.loc[df['reasons'].str.len() == 0, 'reasons'] = None`, this is working perfectly fine. The `loc` syntax is `loc[row, col]` not `loc[:, (row, col)]`

Comment: That does it. Hm, I was super sure I had used the `loc[:, (tuple)]` syntax before... anyway, if you post this as an answer I'll gladly accept it!

Comment: you can use `df.loc[:, (…)]` if you have a MultiIndex ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
df.loc[df['reasons'].str.len() == 0, 'reasons'] = None
```

The correct use of `loc` is `loc[row, col]`, not `loc[:, (row, col)]`

`df.loc[:, (X, Y)]` can be used if you have a **MultiIndex** (see below for an example), but this is not the case here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(None, index=range(2),
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], [1, 2]]))
df.loc[:, ('A', 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2, []], [1, None], [1,3]], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

output(`df`)

```
    col1    col2
0   2       []
1   1       None
2   1       3
```

1. when convert to bool dtype, empty list convert to False
2. `where` make False to NaN

```
df.where(df.astype('bool'))
```

output:

```
    col1    col2
0   2       NaN
1   1       NaN
2   1       3
```

if chk only `col2` column

```
df['col2'].where(df['col2'].astype('bool'))
```